# Understanding JARs and Packages in Java

Tags: java, jar, package

I'm trying to understand how jars and packages work in Java. So to do this, I created a simple test JAR and am trying to use a class contained in that jar. Simple enough, but it is giving me errors like "class not found". Here's the setup:

1) I have a file called MyHelloWorld.java, which will be packaged in a JAR:

```
package com.mytest;

public class MyHelloWorld {
    public String getHello() {
        return "Hello";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

2) I have another file called 'HelloHello.java' which uses the function `getHello()` in com.mytest.MyHelloWorld

```
import com.mytest.*;

public class HelloHello {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        MyHelloWorld hello = new MyHelloWorld();
        System.out.println(hello.getHello());
    }
}
```

3) To package the MyHelloWorld class inside a JAR, I created the folders `com/mytest` in the current directory, and moved MyHelloWorld.java to that folder

4) I compiled MyHelloWorld.java in that folder using `javac MyHelloWorld.java`

5) I ran `jar -cf myhello.jar ./com/mytest/*.class` from the root folder to create the JAR file (as described in http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0028.html)

6) I copied HelloHello.java and myhello.jar to a new folder with nothing else in it, to test this setup

7) `javac -cp ./*.jar HelloHello.java` [succeeds]

8) `java -cp ./*.jar HelloHello` [FAILS] (I also tried just `java HelloWorld', which failed too, with a different error message)

This last statement fails with the message:

```
$java -cp ./*.jar HelloHello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloHello
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloHello
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:315)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:250)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:398)
```

Any idea why it's failing? Any insights you can provide on why it works this way, and how package names are defined inside a JAR etc. would also be appreciated!

Comment: Is there an option of using an IDE so that you don't have to deal with all this?

Comment: This is more for my understanding, but no, not really planning on using an IDE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
java -cp .:./* HelloHello
```

`java` and `javac` treat -cp argument a bit differently. With `java` the `*` in cp will automatically load all the jars it finds in the given location.

Also, the colon `:` is the separator between different classpath elements.

Comment: Thanks, the * is the solution I was looking for - cleaner than adding all the jars individually!

Answer (score 5):

I believe it is looking in the jar for your HelloHello class. You probably need the current folder on the classpath too.

```
java -cp .:myhello.jar HelloHello
```

Comment: Thanks, should that semicolon be a colon? I'm in Unix. Running with the semicolon gives a Usage message. I tried `java -cp .:*.jar HelloHello` and it now fails with `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mytest/MyHelloWorld
 at HelloHello.main(HelloHello.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mytest.MyHelloWorld
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
...etc
`

Comment: Maybe try it with a semicolon, but quote it to protect it from the shell. `java -cp '.;myhello.jar' HelloHello`

Comment: Just tried it and didn't have any success with `java -cp .:*.jar HelloHello`. Had to actually name the jar `java -cp .:myhello.jar HelloHello`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if HelloHello.class is in appropriate directories structure (com/mytest) than change your 8th step:

```
8) java com.mytest.HelloHello //or java -cp .;*.jar com.mytest.HelloHello
```

Comment: So right now, HelloHello is just importing the com.mytest package, of which MyHelloWorld is a class. HelloHello is not a part of that package. I feel like it shouldn't have to be part of the package since in most cases you would be using JARs that define their own packages. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: oh sorry, I thought it was package com.mytest :) Java package organizing classes into modules, it's strongly recommend to put all classes into packages

Answer (score 0):

well, `java HelloHello` works too